# SUM 2 columns nested objects in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Here is how the model links:
project can have multiple tasks,
tasks can have multiple times books against it.
tasktimes have got taskhours and employee on it
Employee has a standardcost.

I am currently working out the sum of the costs of all tasks by looping each task and then multiply the 2 columns i need, and then i sum that.

```
public decimal CalculateCost(IEnumerable<Task> tasks)
{
    decimal total = 0.0M;

    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        var cost = from d in task.TaskTimes
               select new { total = d.Employee.StandardCost * d.TaskHours };

        total = cost.Sum(d => d.total);
    }           
    return total;
}
```

There must be a better way to do this rather than doing that foreach loop but I can't seem to find the syntax. 
Is there a more efficient approach or is this the way to do it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `SelectMany()`

```
var total = tasks.SelectMany(x => x.TaskTimes)
                 .Sum(d => d.Employee.StandardCost * d.TaskHours);
```

Comment: :) .. so that is how that selectmany works.. Thanks- Learnt something new today :)

Comment: @John Woo I have a problem in my query.Can u help me now